# Pandas find average length in days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data and I am trying to get an average days as a result.

My sample data is:

```
orgId              releaseDate                claimDate

bce3e4e4     2021-01-06 23:40:54.930       2021-01-06 21:40:54.930
bce3e4e5     2021-01-06 20:40:54.930       2021-01-06 20:40:54.930
......
```

And I want a result like this:

```
result1 = releaseDate - claimDate
result2 = releaseDate - claimDate
.......
```

And mean like:

```
 result1 + result2 / 2
```

I want the average days. I am new to pandas

Comment: What kind of hours are these? `24, 25, 26` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create column of differency first, convert to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and last aggregate `mean`:

```
df['diff'] = (df.releaseDate - df.claimDate).dt.days

df = df.groupby('orgId', as_index=False)['diff'].mean()
```

Comment: One query will it consider times suppose 1st jan 23:40:54.930 then what would be the days in this. case 1.8 something like that

Comment: @NilaySingh - Do you need ouput new column? Per groups?

Comment: @NilaySingh - Is possible add to answer how looks expected ouput?

Comment: @jazrael dt.days is not calculating number of hours.

Comment: @NilaySingh - yes, it calculate `days`, for hours change `.dt.days` to `.dt.total_seconds() / 3600`

Comment: I want a value like if it is right now (df.releaseDate - df.claimDate) = 2 days 05:00:00 So I want a solution like 2.3 days or 2.1 for that I need to calculate seconds after two days. For that what formula I should use

Comment: @NilaySingh - need `.dt.total_seconds() / 3600 / 24` ?